# how to check whether we are using a view in procedure on not

Tags: mysql, view

i have 150 procedure in my mysql database and also some views. i want to check whether any specific view (ex. suppose view1) are we using in those procedures or not?

is there any command or query by which we can achieve this in mysql

Comment: I don't think there's any way. As far as I can tell, MySQL doesn't provide any way to access the definition of procedures.

Comment: You may be able to use the information_schema.VIEWS & information_schema.ROUTINES tables. The view definition is in the VIEW_DEFINITION column of the VIEWS table (surprisingly). The ROUTINES table gives columns for schema & function name.